# Get dataframe headers and all the unique values in each column i

Tags: python, pandas, header

I have survey data in a dataframe. I can use
print(list(survey_data.columns.values))
to get the headers which are (not listing all 27 columns here but here is the sample)

['Age', 'Gender', 'Country', 'family_history']

I can use the following to get unique values of each column in for loop as follows:

for col in survey_data:

```
print(survey_data[col].unique())
```

[37 44 32 31 33 35 39 42 23 29 36 27 46 41 34 30 40 38 50 24 28 26 22 19
25 45 21 43 56 60 54 55 48 20 57 58 47 62 51 49 53 61]

I want to print the column headers and the unique values as follows

Desired output:

Age = [37 44 32 31 33 35 39 42 23 29 36 27 46 41 34 30 40 38 50 24 28 26 22 19 25 45 21 43 56 60 54 55 48 20 57 58 47 62 51 49 53 61]

Gender = ['F' 'M' 'T']

Country = ['United States' 'Canada' 'United Kingdom' 'Bulgaria' 'France' 'Portugal'
'Switzerland' 'Poland' 'Australia' 'Germany' 'Mexico' 'Brazil' 'Slovenia'
'Costa Rica' 'Austria' 'Ireland' 'India' 'South Africa' 'Russia' 'Italy'
'Netherlands' 'Sweden' 'Colombia' 'Latvia' 'Romania' 'Belgium'
'New Zealand' 'Spain' 'Finland' 'Uruguay' 'Israel'
'Bosnia and Herzegovina' 'Hungary' 'Singapore' 'Japan' 'Nigeria'
'Croatia' 'Norway' 'Thailand' 'Denmark' 'Greece' 'Moldova' 'Georgia'
'China' 'Czech Republic' 'Philippines']

I thought the following statement would get me there.

print(list(survey_data.columns.values) for col in survey_data[col].unique())

Instead I get <generator object  at 0x0000031EF53F3C80>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to show the unique values in all the columns. Please see the below, you can use:

```
for col in survey_data.columns:
    print(survey_data[col].unique().tolist())
```

OR

```
for col in survey_data.columns:
    print(col, survey_data[col].unique().tolist())
```

OR

```
for col in survey_data.columns:
    for unique_val in survey_data[col].unique():
        print(col, unique_val)
```

Comment: This will print unique-values one by one on each line, not the expected format.

Comment: @SerialLazer I have added another option.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change it slightly:

```
for col in survey_data.columns:
  print(col, " = ", list(survey_data[col].unique())
```

Comment: You might also find a dictionary useful.
    d = {col:survey_data[col].unique() for col in survey_data.columns}

Comment: @luthervespers, OP wants in a very specific format (notice the expected output in the qn)

Comment: for col in survey_data.columns:
    print(col,':' , survey_data[col].unique().tolist())   works perfectly.